# Questions on Multilingual site

Tags: aem

I’ve couple of doubts and would request you to please clarify

I've gone through this link http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/multi_site_manager.html

Q1) If we want to create a multilingual site then Language copy in siteadmin tool enables to create copy of existing page from English (en for example) to another language. If I’ve the following structure

```
/content/mysite
               /en
               /ru
               /de
```

But the content of this copied page (ru, de) has to be translated, using Google Translate for example. If we have 100 pages under /content/mysite/en then it will take time to translate each of the 100 pages to the required language.  Is there any other way to do it?

If an author updates content in the /ru site, then how can the same content be updated automatically in the /en and /de sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the multilingual mechanism was not meant to be used with automated translators. Quality of the Google Translator output still isn't production-ready. What's more, Google Translator may be used to [translate page on-the-fly](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/), so there is no need to create separate copy of the original pages.

So yes, each change of the original page requires updating the translated copies, but there is really no way it can be done simpler.

Comment: Hi Tomek, thanks for your reply. Could you please explain in more details "What's more, Google Translator may be used to translate page on-the-fly, so there is no need to create separate copy of the original pages."  How Google translator can be used on-the-fly to translate page? Does this mean I do not need to use language copy and translate manually with the help of Google translator?

Comment: I've one basic doubt, for example I've following structure /content/geometrixx/en/product and /content/geometrixx/ru/product (ru is created by language copy tool). if I initiate Translation workflow from sidekick on http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en/products.html and select Russian then Translation workflow should automatically translate to Russian language or I need to manually change each and every title/paragraph of the newly created page http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/ru/products.html?

Answer (score 1):

As Tomek rightly pointed out, automated translators do not work with the multilingual mechanism.

By starting a **Translation Workflow** (as you mentioned in your comment), you are NOT setting up an automatic translation process. What the **Translation Workflow** does is send out a notification to a specified content author, who would then proceed to manually translate the page to Russian. It sets the page into the Translation view, which is basically a side by side comparison so that the author can look at the base page (in english for example) and then make the requisite changes.

To sum up, setting up a **Translation Workflow** will not automatically translate your page for you, but launch a series of steps which will enable your content author to manually translate the page

Everything I have just said you can find [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/multi_site_manager.html#Managing%20Different%20Language%20Versions%20of%20a%20Website/%22This%20will%20help%22)

Hope this helps